# OptionSet with inverted options

Tags: swift

Say I have a set of options that I can pass to certain processes, for example

```
struct Options: OptionSet {
   let rawValue: Int

   static let floogled = Options(rawValue: 1 << 0)
   static let jibjabbed = Options(rawValue: 1 << 1)
}
```

These are passed to some functions, for example `foo(options: .floogled)` and `bar(options: .jibjabbed)`.

Now, usually when I call those functions, the intention is for all the options to be enabled. So I could define the functions with default values, for example

```
func foo(options: Options = [.floogled, .jibjabbed]) {
   ...
}
```

and so on, and then just call `foo()`. So far so good.

However, in the exceptional cases where I don't want to call those functions with all the options enabled, the usage would be much more intuitive if I could specify which options *not* to enable, rather than which options remain enabled. For example, I would rather like to call `foo(options: .notFloogled)` than `foo(options: .jibjabbed)`.

I can think of two ways to do this. The first way is to change the definition of the option set so that its members are defined negatively; in other words

```
struct OptionsAlternative: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let notFloogled = Options(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let notJibjabbed = Options(rawValue: 1 << 1)
}
```

The functions would then be defined with no options disabled by default; i.e.

```
func foo(options: OptionsAlternative = []) {
   ...
}
```

And I could call it like `foo()` for the default behaviour, or `foo(options: .notFloogled)` when I need to disable specific options. However, I don't want to do this because it makes the implementation of the functions unintuitive. I would have to implement the parts that take the options into account in a double-negative fashion; compare how clumsy this is:

```
if !options.contains(.notFloogled) {
   // Floogling is enabled. Floogle the foo.
   ...
}
```

as opposed to

```
if options.contains(.floogled) {
   // Floogling is enabled. Floogle the foo.
   ...
}
```

The second way is to include members to indicate the presence of options, as in the original solution, *as well as* convenience members to indicate the absence of options. I.e.

```
extension Options {
   /// Not floogled; only jibjabbed.
   static let notFloogled: Options = [.jibjabbed]

   /// Not jibjabbed; only floogled.
   static let notJibjabbed: Options = [.floogled]
}
```

However, this doesn't work if I want to disable multiple options (which was arguably a major reason to use an option set in the first place). For example, if I now call `foo(options: [.notFloogled, .notJibjabbed])`, I get an option set with *both* floogling and jibjabbing enabled, rather than *neither*.

Is there another way of doing what I'm trying to achieve while keeping the implementation and usage as intuitive as possible?

Comment: The OptionSet documentation shows the best way. Just define additional combination options. So have an `all` option and use set subtraction to form your set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OptionSet is a *set*. It has an algebra (SetAlgebra). So you don't need "inverted options"; *you* invert. To invert, just subtract from the "all" case, yourself.

To illustrate (using Apple's own OptionSet example):

```
struct ShippingOptions: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int
    static let nextDay    = ShippingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let secondDay  = ShippingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let priority   = ShippingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let standard   = ShippingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    // include common combinations, including an all case
    static let express: ShippingOptions = [.nextDay, .secondDay]
    static let all: ShippingOptions = [.express, .priority, .standard]
}

// now form the desired options using subtractions
let negatives : ShippingOptions = [.standard] // the ones you _don't_ want
let opts = ShippingOptions.all.subtracting(negatives) // subtract them from "all"!
// and pass `opts`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing. So, do these Options exclude each other? Because your complement `.notFloogled` says it is then `.jibjiabbed` (in the last example). But at the top you can enable both options. What makes it more complicated is that if you have both variables `.floogled` and `.notFloogled` in your struct, you could add both to the array parameter in `foo()` and then which option shall be handled.

To solve the problem with the complement:
I guess the raw value says which option to enable in a binary code.
So the 1 stands for enable and the 0 for do nothing, I assume. 
In the case of using the complement with `.notFloogled`, I would reinterpret the binary code and say 1 is notEnable and 0 do nothing. Otherwise, if you say notFloggled is jibjabbed, you have the problem you already mentioned. So you need a new interpretation for not enable a specific option. It is hard to make suggestion when you don't know how Options is handled.

Nethertheless, I would do something like this maybe

```
struct Options: OptionSet {
   let rawValue: Int

   static let floogled = Options(rawValue: 1 << 0)
   static let jibjabbed = Options(rawValue: 1 << 1)
}

enum OptionsComplement {
   case notFloogled
   case notJibjabbed
}

func foo(options: Options = [.floogled, .jibjabbed]) {
   ...
}

func foo(options: [OptionsComplement] = []) {
   var optionsEnabled: Options = []() //whatever type the array is
   if !options.contains(.notFloggled) {
       optionsEnabled.append(.floogled)
   }
   if !options.contains(.notJibjabbed) {
       optionsEnabled.append(.jibjabbed)
   }
   foo(options: optionsEnabled)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that if I *know* that I will always *pass* the options in the negative style (`notFloogled`/`notJibjabbed`), and the only *read* them in the positive style, I could:

1. Use the negatively-defined option set:

```
struct Options: OptionSet {
   let rawValue: Int

   static let notFloogled = Options(rawValue: 1 << 0)
   static let notJibjabbed = Options(rawValue: 1 << 1)
}
```

2. Extend it with getters (and even setters) for checking the positively-defined options:

```
extension Options {
   var isFloogled: Bool {
      return !self.contains(.notFloogled)
   }

   var isJibjabbed: Bool {
      return !self.contains(.notJibjabbed)
   }
}
```

3. Define the functions to check the positive indicators:

```
func foo(options: Options = []) {
   if options.isFloogled {
      // Floogle the foo
   }
   ...
}
```

4. Still call the functions with the negatively-defined options:

```
foo() // With all options enabled
foo(options: .notFloogled) // With floogling disabled
foo(options: [.notFloogled, .notJibjabbed]) // With floogling jibjabbing disabled
```